# Execute Multiple query if needed in Maatwebsite Excel package, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to export excel from database in laravel. What i want to do is, there is a form by which admin can select "From" , "To" , "Bookingtype" and "Usertype"  . From and To's are date, bookingtype is like Booked or Cancelled and userype is Normal or agent.

When admin select any kind of needs from this, for example when admin selects a date from , from and to then selects cancelled and Agent and press export button, they should get excel. And like wise they can execute different different queries.

So far , i have accomplished to get excel by using three parameters like from, to and bookingtype. But how to use fourth parameter also which is user type ?

This is my code:

```
public function query()
{
    $from = $this->from;
    $to = $this->to;
    $bookingtype = $this->bookingtype;
    $usertype = $this->usertype;

    return Booking::query()->whereBetween('createdAt',[$from, $to])->where('status', '=', $bookingtype);
}
```

And the important is , some time admin can only select from and to and they dont need other two options. So in that situation how to execute only that with one query function ? I am passing these from a from to controller and then class of maatwebsite. So what i am asking is, how to make a query which executes only what are been sent ?

If we send from and to alone, then that should only execute and if we sent three parameters then that should execute like wise ! hope all understands. Do let me know if anything needed.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you if not the let me know

```
$bokingQuery = Booking::query();
$from = $this->from;
$to = $this->to;
if(isset($from) && isset($to))
$bokingQuery->whereBetween('createdAt',[$from, $to]);
$bookingtype = $this->bookingtype;
if(isset($bookingtype ))
$bokingQuery->where('status',$bookingtype);
$usertype = $this->usertype;
if(isset($usertype)) //
$bokingQuery->whereHas('usertype',, function($query) use ($usertype) {
    $query->whereUserType($usertype);
});
$bokingQuery->get();
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usertype' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `bookings` where `status` = CANCELLED and `createdAt` between 2018-09-13 14:58 and 2018-09-30 14:58 and `status` = CANCELLED and `usertype` = Choose options)`    As usertype is another model names User, and i had a relation with booking table with userid

Comment: updated the code please check and if its not working then please provide model details so i can help you more efficiently

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::usertype does not exist. This is the error which i am getting now !

Comment: you have to provide both model details

Comment: class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
   
    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Booking', 'userid');
    }

    public function walletUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Wallet', 'userid');
    }
    
    public function supports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Help', 'userid');
    }
    
    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }

Comment: class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'bookingid';
   
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userid');
    }
    
    public function getDateOfIssueAttribute($value) {
        
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-M-Y , h:m a');
    }
    
   
    public function getDojAttribute($value) {
        
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-M-Y , h:m a');
    }
    
    
}

Comment: where did you defined your bookingtype coulmn

Comment: why should i define that in model ? I just use relations and take usertype from User table and booking table

Comment: i am li'l bit confused now the above the above all counms are in the user model

Comment: Kindly do let me know what, needed more ? Is there possible to send files to u ?

Comment: no ddon't need files  we can't share uore peronel details here only tell me one thing where is your usertype column

Comment: its in Users Table, and Users table is in relation with Booking table. So while querying booking table , i can use relation with user table and get user data also !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180613/discussion-between-shaielndra-gupta-and-arvindh).

Answer (score 0):

You must be create your conditions due to the input parameters.

```
public function query(){
    $conditions=[];

    if(isset($this->from) && $this->from){
        $conditions[]=['createdAt', '>=', $this->from];
    }

    if(isset($this->to) && $this->to){
        $conditions[]=['createdAt', '<=', $this->to];
    }

    if(isset($this->bookingtype) && $this->bookingtype){
        $conditions[]=['status', $this->bookingtype];
    }

    if(isset($this->usertype) && $this->usertype){
        $conditions[]=['usertype', $this->usertype];
    }


    return Booking::where($conditions)->get();
}
```

Comment: usertype is from another table, i have related usertype into bookings using userid ! while using ur codes, i got an error ` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usertype' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `bookings` where (`createdAt` >= 2018-09-13 14:47 and `createdAt` <= 2018-09-30 14:47 and `status` = CANCELLED and `usertype` = agent)) `

Comment: And while if i try to not select user type from the form then i get a error as ` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usertype' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `bookings` where (`createdAt` >= 2018-09-13 14:47 and `createdAt` <= 2018-09-30 14:47 and `status` = CANCELLED and `usertype` = Choose options)) `